# How can I run my code outside an Angular NgZone

Tags: angular, zone

I have a function which is very I/O hungry, and seems to trigger millions of detection changes, although nothing is updated in the DOM while the function is running. Someone recommended to use [NgZone.runOutsideAngular](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone#runOutsideAngular) or even `ngZone: 'noop'`.

In both cases my function still takes 30 times as long as compared to pure running in Node.

```
    console.log('Start');
    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      repo.copyCache()
        .finally(() => {
          console.log('Done');
        });
    });
```

Does anyone know, why despite `runOutsideAngular` my callstack contains `ZoneAwarePromise` and reroutes all my `copyFile` calls?

[image]

## TLDR

Why does `ZoneAwarePromise` and `zone-evergreen.js` appear in my callstacks, although I create and execute them within `this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular`?

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a look at implementing a "Web Worker", which would put your function on a background thread.

Documentation for Angular Web Workers is at https://angular.io/guide/web-worker

Comment: Agree, it would be something to investigate. But I am sporadically updating a progress bar (inside the context), so workers don't work as well here

Comment: There's built-in support for passing messages between the web worker and the main thread, intended exactly for your use case.

Comment: I will check that out. Thanks for the follow up!